# How to add an element to an array using a key as ordinal element in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How to add an element to an array using a key as ordinal element?

Before all, this is a theoretical question, and **I'm looking for an answer** instead of a way to reach the goal.

I've a function that generate a key, and I'was asking myself if there's a key to add to an array an element as ordinal element

```
$a=[];
$key=generateKey();
$a[$key]="pino";
var_export($a);
```

I was hoping this result:

```
array (
  0 => 'pino'
)
```

A more advanced situation could be

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  '7239ea2b5dc943f61f3c0a0276c20974' => 'b',
  1 => 'c',
  'c180aaadf5ab10fb3a733f43f3ffc4b3' => 'lino',
  '48bb6e862e54f2a795ffc4e541caed4d' => 'gino',
  2 => 'pino',      // <- take 2 as index
)
```

**EDIT**

An hypothetic implementation of generateKey:

```
function generateKey($array){
    $_rv=0;
    foreach ($array as $k => $v){
        if(is_numeric($k)==false){
            continue;
        }
        $_rv=$k+1;
    }
    return $_rv;
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: `$a[] = "pino";` ?

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa, sorry, I've correct the title and the question, hope more clear now

Comment: @iainn, yes I know, but the question is how to do like this:  $a[$key]="pino";

Comment: What exactly does generateKey() generate, since the output of this function defines what the key is. If it would generate 0 then the result you've posted here should be correct.

Comment: @RobinRijkeboer generateKey() is a placeholder for an unknow value, now I'll add an exaple function

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what was your real question... but as I have understood by your comment...

```
$a=[];
$key=generateKey();
```

to assign key to arry in php... below line is correct.

```
$a[$key]="pino";
```

If you want data in form of {key:value}...

```
var_export(json_encode($a));
```

Comment: The goal is to add "pino" to the array $a with a numeric index, but using a variable $key as array key, as the same way is done by: $a[]="pino"

Comment: **$a[$key]='pino'** this line is correct.... check your generateKey() function what value it is giving.....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to get highest numerical index of an array. You may try this:

```
$maxIdx = max(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_numeric')) ?: -1;
$array[$maxIdx + 1] = 'pino';
```

Comment: Even if you function is way more smart than mine should be heavy when many elements are involved

Comment: Then just cache max numerical index while you're creating the array.

Comment: that's even better as solution, but it's not the goal of the question

Answer (score 0):

Looking the documentation of [array-key-last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php) I realized that the `count` function could achieve to generate a new numeric key without be cpu bounding:

```
$key=count($a);
$a[$key]="pino";
var_export($a);
```

Comment: `$a = array('1'=>'bla'); count($a) == 1`

Comment: correct aproach `max(array_keys($a))+1`; It works even whey keys are strings and digits

Comment: @splash58 it's correct for a bulletproof solution. I should set clear bounds in the question: the array is populated only by 2 functions. The 1st: use unique alphabetical keys. The 2nd integer keys. But I was expecting a really different solution.